# can multiple key value pairs be inserted in a single tx in tendermint?

Tags: blockchain, cosmos, tendermint

```
curl -s 'localhost:26657/broadcast_tx_commit?tx="zid=1 title=xyz"'
```

Can something be done like this?

I want to store multiple data in a single transaction, so can it be done using key value pairs or any other technique that would work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it's up to you on how your application parses the transaction. If your application (sounds like a key-value database) can accept multiple key-value pairs separated by a space like in your example, then this'll work fine.

See the *kvstore* example. You could easily modify it to accept multiple key-value pairs.

Comment: I tried. It's not accepting multiple key value pairs.

Comment: Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: would be great help

Comment: What changes did you make to kvstore? Show us what you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is the correct syntax to use it:

```
curl -s 'localhost:26657/broadcast_tx_commit?tx="zid=1"&tx="title=xyz"'
```

Since `'tx'` itself is a key in order to input multiple key you need to add it as a transaction itself.